# Recommended data structure for representing Object relations (Objects inside Object)

Tags: java, data-structures

I got a problem creating a data structure where i need to represent an Object which contains Objects, each of one containing its own Objects.
I need to represent something like this:

```
[
  { id: "fruit",
    name: "Fruit",
    parentId: null,
    type:[
           { id: "apple",
             name: "Apple",
             parentId: "supercategory-fruit",
             type:[
                    { id: "greenApple"
                      name: "Green Apple",
                      parentId: "category-fruit-apple",
                      type: []
                     },
                     { id: "redApple"
                       name: "Red Apple"
                       parentId: "category-fruit-apple",
                       type: []
                     },
                     {pinkApple},
                     {..}
                   ]
            },
            {orange},
            {melon},
            {..}
          ]
  },
  {meat},
  {vegetables},
  {..}
]
```

So i got everything in my database plus their relations (through my parentId field).
I need to find the best possible data structure to fill in with all that info so to send it in my API and nicely present it.

PS. ideally i want to take only the ids and names of each object and create a smaller data structure, but i think its a little more complicated.

Any idea would be nice!

Thank you

My first try was creating a `Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>>`.
The problem with Map is that i (now realized) can't have a whole Object as a Key. So my code returned the Object's id as a Key, even if i put the whole Object inside.

Comment: Why do you think you *can't have a whole object as key*? Can you show us your java code?

Comment: Cause when i tried it it gave me back only the id of the object.

Answer (score 0):

What about a class like this:

```
public class Obj {
    String id;
    String name;
    Obj parent;
    List<Obj> type;
}
```

You can change parent to `String` if you don't need the instance.

Comment: I would love to create a new class, but i think i ll need to change lots of things about the model then (like JAXBContext or index fields), not entirely sure yet though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a common/simplest representation of this object try defining a class like:

```
public class Content{
 String id ;  //"fruit"
 String name; // "Fruit"
 String parentId; //   parentId: null
 List<Content> type;  // list of other items.
}
```

You can put the whole json into a  this class:

```
public class Contents{
 List<Content> items;
}
```

and then iterate over to items.